# std::map insert, candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided

Tags: c++, dictionary, std

Here's my header:

```
class L {
    public:
        L(wstring);
        ~L();
    private:
        wstring ipath;
        std::unique_ptr<freeling::tokenizer> tokenizer;
};
```

Here's my class:

```
L::L(wstring language) {

}

L::~L() {

}
```

And here's main:

```
std::map<std::string, L> l;
l.insert(std::make_pair("a", L(L"b")));
```

When I compile, I get an imense list of errors, but the end is:

```
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_map.h:807:9: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:18:42: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
     l.insert(std::make_pair("a", L(L"b")));
```

Here's the entire error: https://pastebin.com/iU9bsBVH

**Curiously, if I just remove the destructor's definition and declaration, the code compiles**

Comment: Can you please copy-paste the *full* and *complete* error output? Including possible informational notes.

Comment: What does the constructor of the LPro class look like?

Comment: Needs a [mcve].

Comment: Hi, I've put a working example, could you guys take a look?

Comment: Your code compiles without errors, see here: https://ideone.com/765h7L. Did you inlcude `#include <map>` and `#include <string>`? Further your error is saying something about templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error in first line of code you have posted here

```
std::pair<iterator,bool> insert( const value_type& value );
```

It you should pass two values to insert.

For example

```
std::pair <std::string,double> product1;                     // default constructor
std::pair <std::string,double> product2 ("tomatoes",2.30);   // value init
std::pair <std::string,double> product3 (product2);  // copy constructor
```

Comment: I've made some changes, would you mind taking a look?

Answer (score 0):

The following code does compile.

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

using std::string;

class LPro
{
    public:
        LPro(const wchar_t* _pr){ m_pr = const_cast<wchar_t*> (_pr); }

    private:
        wchar_t* m_pr;
};

int main()
{
    std::map<string, LPro> l_pro;
    l_pro.insert(std::make_pair("pt", LPro(L"pt")));

    return 0;
}
```

did you by accident forgot the 'l' in l_pro?
It seems so from the compiler comment.

Comment: why LPro(const wchar_t* _pr)? Mine is:         LPro(std::wstring language);
what's the difference?

Comment: Two different object. But I don't think it's the problem. Please edit the question with the full code so I can see and answer.